# Drag & Drop for older Android not precise

Tags: android, button, view, drag-and-drop, gesturedetector

So I'm attempting to make a "magnetic poetry" type application. Users will move various Button widgets on the screen. I am using a Button widget since it is the closest to the look of the magnet, though I am open to other options!

The objects are not properly moving with my finger. They're close but they're not exactly in line with my finger. The X coordinate on my phone seems to be fine, but the Y corrdinate is off. Is this perhaps due to the title bar?

```
private final static int DRAGGING_OFF = 0;
private final static int DRAGGING_ON = 1;

private int dragStatus;

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector; 
private int mOffsetX;
private int mOffsetY;
private LayoutParams mOldParams;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(!mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if(dragStatus == DRAGGING_ON) {
                Log.e(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Dragging! RAW -- " + event.getRawX() + " : " + event.getRawY() + " NOT RAW -- " + event.getX() + " : " + event.getY());
                int rawX, rawY;
                int finalX, finalY;

                rawX = (int) event.getRawX();
                rawY = (int) event.getRawY();

                finalX = rawX - mOffsetX;
                finalY = rawY - mOffsetY;

                lp.setMargins(finalX, finalY, 0, 0);
                this.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }

            return true;
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(dragStatus == DRAGGING_ON) {
                dragStatus = DRAGGING_OFF;
                Log.e(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Stopped dragging!");
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {          
        int[] location = new int[2];
        Log.e(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Down! RAW -- " + e.getRawX() + " : " + e.getRawY() + " NOT RAW -- " + e.getX() + " : " + e.getY());
        dragStatus = DRAGGING_ON;

        // Sets the current location of the View in the int[] passed to it; x then y.
        getLocationInWindow(location);
        Log.e(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Down location: " + location[0] + " " + location[1]);

        mOffsetX = (int) e.getRawX() - location[0];
        mOffsetY = (int) e.getRawY() - location[1];
        mOldParams = getLayoutParams();

        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're not getting the DELTA of the current touch point Y and the cached, last touch point y. You need something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        image.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                matrix.getValues(m); //copy matrix values into array

                PointF currentXYTouchPoint = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //start of pressed gesture
                        lastXYTouchPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY()); //save the last touchpoint
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //calculate the change in finger position
                        float deltaX = currentXYTouchPoint.x - lastXYTouchPoint.x;
                        float deltaY = currentXYTouchPoint.y - lastXYTouchPoint.y;
                        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY); //move the entire image by the deltas
                        image.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                        // save this last starting touchpoint
                        lastXYTouchPoint.set(currentXYTouchPoint.x, currentXYTouchPoint.y);
                        break;
                }

                textView.setText("TouchPoint started at " + currentXYTouchPoint.x + ", " + currentXYTouchPoint.y + " & the matrix is now " + Arrays.toString(m));
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Adapt it to your own purposes, but the basic idea is there.

Comment: That seems like it's a doable method. I just need to test it against getLocationInWindow() to make sure that the numbers I get from there can be used directly to do math and pass back to LayoutParams.setMargins()

Comment: So it turns out that the issue I was having wasn't related to using my method or using the delta method you suggested. It seems to be more related to the title bar and status bar height. The numbers I am getting are relative to the screen but the information about the location that I set are supposed to be relative to the window, so it's off on the Y coordinate. Somebody found this for me: http://andmobidev.blogspot.com/2010/01/getting-height-of-status-and-title-bar.html